# using variables in ajax function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, jquery, web

I have an ajax function which retrieves data from an xml file which is on a server. I am trying to get that file which only appears when you are within a specific area (therefore using longitude and latitude). In order to do that, I need to append the longitude and latitude in the URL (which is in the ajax function) so I can access the file. I have declared 2 global variables outside the ajax function, holding the longitude and latitude. But I do not know how to call the variable inside the ajax function (so that I can append to the url to retrieve the file). Can anyone please tell me how to do it? Please give me some examples.

Thank you

Here is the code: (I haven't put my exact url)

```
    var geolocation = {};
    geolocation.latitude = 0;
    geolocation.longitude = 0;
    //Check if geolocation is available
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
    geolocation.latitude = p.coords.latitude;
    geolocation.longitude = p.coords.longitude;
    alert(geolocation.latitude + " " + geolocation.longitude);
    }, function (error) {
    alert("Failed to get GPS location");
    });
    } else {
    alert("Failed to get GPS working");
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "url",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: xmlParser
    });
    });
    function xmlParser(xml) {
       $('#wrap2').append("<ul></ul>");
       $(xml).find("photo").each(function () {
       var festname = $(this).find('name').text();
       var fest_url = $(this).find('url').text();
       var fest_filename = $(this).find('filename').text();
       $("<li></li>").html(festname + "" + fest_url + "" + fest_filename).appendTo("#wrap2 ul");
     });
    }
```

Comment: If you don't show your code, what makes you think people will be able to usefully help you? At the very least, not showing it makes it much harder and more time-consuming for them to do so.

Comment: If you have defined the variables globally, then you can use it directly.

Comment: Agree - Code will help us.

Comment: I have added my code sample

Comment: @OghaleBlessingEtomu: Okay, so my answer directly applies. Did you have a follow-up question?

Comment: @OghaleBlessingEtomu - is your issue how to build a url or how to make an AJAX call with jQuery?  You don't have to use a URL. TJC gave 2 good examples below.

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are truly globals (which I would strongly recommend avoiding), then you can access them from anywhere. That's what the term "global" means.

And so:

```
$.ajax({
    url:   "/path/to/the/file?foo=" + encodeURIComponent(fooGlobal) + "&bar=" & encodeURIComponent(barGlobal),
    // ...
});
```

...or similar. You can also have jQuery encode and append them for you (I'm assuming this is a `GET` operation):

```
$.ajax({
    url:   "/path/to/the/file",
    data:  {
        foo:  fooGlobal,
        bar:  barGlobal
    },
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I tried this method but it did not work

Comment: @OghaleBlessingEtomu: Any time you find yourself writing "...did not work..." or similar in a technical question, backspace over it and write down *exactly* what you expected, *exactly* what happened instead, why you think that's wrong, and the output of any error reporting system there may be (all major browsers have a console now where errors are shown for instance). Both of the above, done correctly, work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways: since you have created (evil) global variables, you can just reference them from within a function (JS does scope-scanning):

```
var globalVar = 1234;
function someFunction()
{
    console.log(globalVar);
}
```

This works, no problem. If you have a variable, declared within a function, that has the same name as a global variable, then you can also specify `window`, as the namespace:

```
var someVar = 'global';
function someFunction()
{
    var someVar = 'function scope';
    console.log(window.someVar);//logs global
    console.log(someVar);//logs function scope
}
```

Lastly, and this is to be preferred frankly, is passing the data as an argument to the function, whenever you call it:

```
function myFunction (long, lat)
{
     console.log('do stuff with ' + long + ' & ' + lat);
}
myFunction(123, 456);//logs do stuff with 123 & 456
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how do I then call the variable in the ajax url string?